# regex used in javascript array indexOf

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I need to find the index of the word in array .But for the following scenario

```
var str="hello how are you r  u fineOr not .Why u r not fine.Please tell wats makes u notfiness".
var splitStr=str.split(" ");
//in splitStr array fineOr is stored at da index of 6.
//in splitStr array notfiness is stored at da index of 18.
var i=splitStr.indexOf("**fine**");
var k=splitStr.lastindexOf("**fine**");
console.log('value i-- '+i); it should log value 6
console.log('value k-- '+k); it should log value 18
```

How do I need to pass the regex for searching the string "fine" for the function indexOf of array?

Comment: You can not pass a regular expression there, because that is not how indexOf works.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, maybe it's worth a feature request? https://tc39.github.io/process-document/

Answer (score 11):

You can also use filter on the array of words,

http://jsfiddle.net/6Nv96/

```
var str="hello how are you r  u fineOr not .Why u r not fine.Please tell wats makes u notfiness";
var splitStr=str.split(" ");
splitStr.filter(function(word,index){
    if(word.match(/fine/g)){/*the regex part*/
    /*if the regex is dynamic and needs to be set by a string, you may use RegExp and replace the line above with,*/
    /*var pattern=new RegExp("fine","g");if(word.match(pattern)){*/

        /*you may also choose to store this in a data structure e.g. array*/
        console.log(index);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

After `.split(' ')` you will get `splitStr` as an array , so you have to loop through that

```
 var str="hello how are you r  u fineOr not .Why u r not fine.Please tell wats makes u notfiness";
 var splitStr = str.split(" ");
 var indexs = [];
 splitStr.forEach(function(val,i){

     if(val.indexOf('fine') !== -1) {  //or val.match(/fine/g)
        indexs.push(i);
     }
 });

console.log(indexs) // [7, 13, 18]

console.log('First index is ', indexs[0]) // 7
console.log('Last index is ', indexs[indexs.length-1]) // 18
```

Comment: you should use reduce rather than creating an array, using forEach, and then pushing onto the array

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex) library then you can use _.findIndex() method.

```
var targetStr = 'string2';

var r = _.findIndex(['string1', 'string2'], function(str){
  return targetStr.indexOf(str) >= 0;
});

//Index is always >=0 

if(r >= 0){
 //result found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care much about the performance, here is a solution

```js
const str = "hello how are you r  u fineOr not .Why u r not fine.Please tell wats makes u notfiness";
const splitStr = str.split(" ");
let i = splitStr.findIndex(v => /.*fine.*/.test(v));
let k = splitStr.length - splitStr.reverse().findIndex(v => /.*fine.*/.test(v));
console.log(--i);
console.log(--k);
```

Answer (score 2):

The only ES6 answers here continue to use regular expressions, but that is not necessary.  If regexps are your performance concern, you can avoid them:

```
const str = "hello how are you r  u fineOr not .Why u r not fine.Please tell wats makes u notfiness";
const splitStr = str.split(" ");
let i = splitStr.findIndex(str => str.includes("fine"));
let k = splitStr.length - splitStr.reverse().findIndex(str => str.includes("fine"));
console.log(`i = ${--i}\nk = ${--k}`);
```

Here is a codepen that demonstrates this: https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/LYEpmwX

There might be more efficient ways than `.reverse()`, and you can declare a function if you prefer that to 2 duplicate arrow functions. But this eliminates regexp entirely and should perform well.

Answer (score 1):

To address the OP, which I feel has not been done yet, here's a round-about way to indexOf by regex using a condensed iteration:

```
var arr = ['foo','bar','this','that','another'];
var re = /^[Tt]hi[a-z]$/; // expected match is 'this'
var ind = arr.indexOf((function(){
    var i;
    for(i in arr)
        if(re.test(arr[i]))
            return arr[i];
    })());
// ind = 2 which is accurate

re = /i_dont_exist/; // expected not to match
ind = arr.indexOf((function(){
    var i;
    for(i in arr)
        if(re.test(arr[i]))
            return arr[i];
    })());
// ind = -1, also accurate
```

Answer (score 0):

If source string can be complex and not easilly splitted by ' ', maybe you should use a more robust approach. If you don't mind to include an external library, you could use [nat-js](https://github.com/erick-fernandes/nat-js) to tokenize the source string. Here is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example 04 - Word Index</title>

  <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="../js/lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qunit/1.12.0/qunit.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="../js/lib/nat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Example 04 - Word Index</h1>

<p>
You can use nat-js to tokenize a text and build some logic over it.
</p>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var searchString = 'fine';
    var sourceString = 'hello how are you r  u fineOr not .Why u r not fine.Please tell wats makes u notfiness';
    var tkz = new nat.tokenizer();
    var tokens = tkz.execute(sourceString);

    var i = 0;
    var result = [];
    for(var t in tokens) {
        var tk = tokens[t];
        if ( tk.value.indexOf(searchString)>=0 ) {
            result.push({
                what: tk.value,
                where: i
            });
        }
        i++;
    }

    result.forEach(function(r) {
        console.log('found ' + r.what + ' in ' + r.where);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which has not been metioned is the following:

```
var str = "hello how are you r u fineOr not .Why u r not fine.Please 
tell wats makes u notfiness";
var splitStr = str.split(" ");

function findIndex(splitStr){
  return splitStr.findIndex(function (element) {
    return element.indexOf('fine') === 0;
  })
}
console.log(findIndex(splitStr)); // 6
```

Explanation:

The **findIndex** method iterates over each element of the array and returns the index of the desired element when the anonymous function provided returns true.

**element.indexOf** in this case evaluates each element as a string and will evaluate to **0** once it reaches an element where the desired word i.e.  ('fine') appears. Once evaluated to 0 and compared to 0, will return true. This will make **findIndex** return the index of the element at which the function evaluated to true.